# SQL Server CE 4.0 Entity Framework Maximum Row Size Exception?

Tags: sql-server-ce

I have a simple database with 1 table and 8 columns.  The table has about twenty rows in it.  See the exact schema below.  However when trying to insert certain records I get the following error:

> The table definition or the row size exceeds the maximum row size of 8060 bytes.

Why would I be getting this.  The table is not that big at all yet.  What do you think?

[image]

Comment: Please, could you post what is really sent to the DB. You can use profiler

Comment: `nvarchar(4000) = 8000 bytes, twice nvarchar(50) = 2 x 100 bytes` - that alone is 8200 bytes (more than the 8060 bytes limit) ....

Comment: ah...... so if i'm sending a row with 4000 characters plus the additional data... this would hose it

Answer (score 1):

nvarchar is Unicode and requires 2 bytes per character internally, so your nvarchar(4000) is actually 4000*2 bytes=8000. Add the rest ....

Comment: so how could you truely ever have an nvarchar(4000) column in your DB?  makes no sense.  I'm just trying to store 4000 characters of text (numbers/letters)

Comment: SQL will allow you to do it, because it is variable. Do you really need Unicode? If not, stick with VARCHAR or use VARCHAR/NVARCHAR(MAX)

Comment: use ntext (nvarchar(MAX) does not exosi in SQL Compact)